# Subscribe to tags on Stack Exchange Enterprise through email

Tags: feature-request, so-enterprise

I'm trying to subscribe to specific tags on both Stack Overflow and my company's enterprise Stack Overflow.

I found that I was able to do that with the public version of Stack Overflow but not in the enterprise version. Specifically the "advanced tag subscriptions"
[image]

We are trying to monitor an upcoming feature with a specific set of tags and would like to receive email notifications whenever someone posts with a specific tag so we can quickly respond.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Could you get the RSS feed and then use an RSS-to-email service?

Comment: I also tried using the RSS Feeds feature within Outlook with no luck. Hitting issues with pulling from the Enterprise Stack Exchange. It works fine for the public version though.

Comment: The "advanced tag subscriptions" on SE sites lead to https://stackexchange.com/filters, wonder where the link on the Enterprise version lead to?

Comment: There is no link on the Enterprise version, which is the source of my problem.